# Copy data from one workbook to another workbook last row

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code to copy data from one workbook to another but it is giving me the error:

> subscript Out of Range

Also this code does not copy data to target sheet the last row.

```
Sub CopyDataNEW()
    Dim sBook_t As Workbook
    Dim sBook_s As Workbook
    Dim wbPath_t As String
    Dim wbPath_s As String

    wbPath_t = "F:\TESt\DB_BA.xlsx"
    wbPath_s = "F:\TESt\PPC_BA.xlsm"

    Set sBook_s = Workbooks.Open(wbPath_s)
    Set sBook_t = Workbooks.Open(wbPath_t)

    sBook_s.Sheets("cstdata").Range("A2:EK2").Copy Destination:=sBook_t.Sheets("cstdatalist").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Comment: double check that "PPC_BA.xlsm" workbook has actually a sheet named after "cstdata" and "TESt\DB_BA.xlsx" workbook has actually a sheet named after "cstdatalist"

Answer (score 0):

Edited your code, should work:

```
Sub CopyDataNEW()
    Dim sBook_t As Workbook
    Dim sBook_s As Workbook
    Dim wbPath_t As String
    Dim wbPath_s As String
    Dim lRow2 as Long
    'make sure file destination is correct, file name is correct, and file extension is correct here
    'you will get subscript out of range error here if these are not accurate
    wbPath_t = "F:\TESt\DB_BA.xlsx"
    wbPath_s = "F:\TESt\PPC_BA.xlsm"

    Set sBook_s = Workbooks.Open(wbPath_s)
    Set sBook_t = Workbooks.Open(wbPath_t)
    'Find last row in paste workbook
    lRow2 = sBook_t.Sheets("cstdatalist").Range("A" & sBook_t.Sheets("cstdatalist").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'copy and paste
    sBook_s.Sheets("cstdata").Range("A2:EK2").Copy
    sBook_t.Sheets("cstdatalist").Range("A" & lRow2).Paste
    'clear clip board
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'clear objects
    Set sBook_s = Nothing
    Set sBook_t = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your code, but it is still giving me subscript error i double check the file name and location it is correct dont know whats the issue

Comment: @BahadurAli are the sheet names in the correct workbooks? Meaning is "cstdadalist" in DB_BA.xlsx, and is "cstdata" in PPC_BA.xlsm? Maybe you have confused them?

Comment: no i am not confused, sheets names and workbooks name both are fine

Comment: @BahadurAli where is the code stopping when giving the error?

Comment: I am Not sure its just givign msg box error subsript