# Excel VBA copying worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

i would like to open two Excel Files and from each of the two Excel Files copying one distinct sheet into a new workbook so that this new workbook contains the two sheets of the ones first loaded.  I tried to use

`workbook("old.xls").worksheets(2).copy  after:=workbook("new.xls").worksheets(1)`

but I always get a Runtime error.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: there could be lots of problem, but it's too hard to tell with the little bit of code provided. Can you please post a more complete code base to help us help you solve the problem (see [mcve])

Comment: See this question and answer for some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204636/copy-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-workbook-last-row

Answer (score 0):

You can copy one sheet from the 1st workbook. this will create a new workbook, then copy the 2nd sheet to that new workbook.

```
Sub CopySheetsToNewWB()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim BK As Workbook


    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Old.xls")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Old2.xls")

    With wb1
        .Sheets("Sheet2").Copy
    End With

    Set BK = ActiveWorkbook

    With wb2
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=BK.Sheets(1)
    End With


    BK.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\NewWB.xls"
    BK.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample.  I will try.

Comment: You need to pick this as an answer, don't leave threads unanswered!